# Ansible: ansible-playbook delegate_to error

Tags: ansible

I have a playbook, this is a part of it.

...

```
- name: Wait for SSH to start
  wait_for:
    host: "{{ newmachines.instances[0].public_ip }}"
    port: 22
    timeout: 300
  delegate_to: localhost
```

...
ansible-playbook --check create_instance.yml.old
ERROR: delegate_to is not a legal parameter of an Ansible Play

ansible-playbook --version
ansible-playbook 1.9.4
  configured module search path = None

How can i fix it?

Answer (score -4, accepted):

The parameters to the task should be in the format of `key=value`, not `key:value`.  This is confusing Ansible.  What you want is this:

```
- name: Wait for SSH to start
  wait_for:
    host="{{ newmachines.instances[0].public_ip }}"
    port=22
    timeout=300
  delegate_to: localhost
```

Modifiers to the task, like `delegate_to`, `with_items`, etc. should use `:`.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe you should check your indentation (tabs/spaces)? Ansible seems to think the `delegate_to` is on the play level, while it is on the task level from the looks of the code you posted.

This doesn't work:

```
---
- hosts: myhost
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
  - name: Wait for SSH to start
    wait_for:
      host: myhost
      port: 22
      timeout: 300
  delegate_to: localhost
```

It fails with the error you mention:

```
$ ansible-playbook -i hosts pb.yaml
ERROR! 'delegate_to' is not a valid attribute for a Play
```

While this does (note the indentation difference):

```
---
- hosts: myhost
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
  - name: Wait for SSH to start
    wait_for:
      host: myhost
      port: 22
      timeout: 300
    delegate_to: localhost
```

The output:

```
$ ansible-playbook -i hosts pb.yaml

PLAY [myhost] ****************************************************************

TASK [Wait for SSH to start] ***************************************************
ok: [myhost-> localhost]

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
myhost: ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0
```

Answer (score 1):

@serko that playbook works for me using `ansible-playbook` 1.9.4

```
---
# main.yml
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    - name: Wait for SSH to start
      wait_for:
        host: "localhost"
        port: 22
        timeout: 300
      delegate_to: localhost
```

.

```
$ ansible-playbook --check main.yml

PLAY [all] ********************************************************************

TASK: [Wait for SSH to start] *************************************************
skipping: [127.0.0.1 -> localhost]
ok: [127.0.0.1 -> localhost]

PLAY RECAP ********************************************************************
127.0.0.1                  : ok=0    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0
```